# Рыбный вопрос: есть ли множественное число у слова СЁМГА?

Tags: морфология, выбор-слов

Можно сказать

> окуни, щуки, сомы

но нельзя

> **трески*

Вопрос: есть ли множественное число у слова *сёмга* (в значении отдельной рыбины, а не вида как такового).

Answer (score 4):

> Вопрос: есть ли множественное число у слова сёмга?

Есть. [См.:](http://starling.rinet.ru/morph.htm)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Можно ли сказать "две сёмги"?

Можно. [Так говорят.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%B8%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%B8%22&tbm=bks&start=0)

Помета "обычно собир." в словарях не говорит о том, что словом *сёмга* нельзя назвать [одну рыбину этой породы.](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F1%E5%EC%E3%E0&all=x)

**P.S.**

[Из школьного задачника по математике:](https://books.google.ru/books?id=IWyLAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&dq=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%B8%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=2kieVdK1J8PMyAOd07LoCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%B8%22&f=false)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В комментарии выше было указано, что *две сёмги* - это родительный падеж единственного числа. Другое дело, что сказать *три счастья* или *две застенчивости* никак нельзя. Но можно сказать *Можешь передать мне тех двух окуней.* Но не звучит: *У тебя не будет пары сёмг до завтра? Хочу ухи наварить.* Так что такая аргументация здесь не подходит.

Comment: _Но не звучит..._ === А здесь, по-моему, вполне звучит (из школьного учебника): _Был конфискован катер, дорогие сети. Виновный выплатил 150 рублей — стоимость_ **двух семг**. _Было совершено преступление, которое называется браконьерством. Проанализируйте этот случай браконьерства..._

Comment: Ни в одном словаре мне мн.ч. не указывается. Скорее мн.ч. мало употребительно.

Comment: Удалось найти в Национальном корпусе.Колоссальные, сине-стальные, точно рыцарские доспехи, висели рядами ***семги*** и осетры, сверкая косыми розовыми срезами. ***[Самуил Алешин. ***Встречи на грешной земле (2001)] Однажды в сеть попалось больше десяти крупных ***семг***, так они лодку чуть к норвежскому берегу не утащили. [Владимир Арро. Дом прибежища // «Звезда», 2002]

Comment: _Серж: Ни в одном словаре мне мн.ч. не указывается._ === Серж, но я же дал в своём ответе ссылку на сайт http://starling.rinet.ru/morph.htm, составленный по материалам Грамматического словаря Зализняка. === Форма мн. ч. приводится и в ряде других  словарей. Указана она и в "Большом орфоэпическом словаре" РАН (2012): **СЁМГА**, сёмги, _мн._ сёмги, сёмгам.

Comment: @slava1947 Получается употребление во множественном числе допустимо, но не является частотным.

Comment: _Получается, употребление во множественном числе допустимо, но не является частотным._ === Да.

Comment: >> Другое дело, что сказать три счастья или две застенчивости никак нельзя. "Вот и встретились ДВА ОДИНОЧЕСТВА" -- а так можно.

Answer (score 2):

Семга в словарях дается с пометой: собирательно.

В приведенных же вами примерах: окуня, сома - не являются мн.ч. Окончания ***-а-я*** являются родительным падежом.

Мн.ч. Окуни, сомы.

То же: две трески - род.пад.

Comment: Согласен. Исправил!